# Is a closed form version of the Look and Say sequence useful?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, closed-form

I have discovered a closed form function for the Look and Say sequence, which relies only on the operators $+,\ -,\ \div,\ \times,$ infinite sums, and finite products. Call this function $L$. It takes in a term as input and outputs the next term. That is, $L(x_n) = x_{n+1}$, where $x_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ term in the Look and Say sequence. Is this useful to any field or any specific problem?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-94OKifRzqxWFpYdGpETVdMbXM) is a link to the entire function.

$$
\begin{array}
{|c|c|c|c|} \hline \text{Equality} & eq(x,y): & \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{B} & 1-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-y)| \\ 
\hline \text{Digit At} & dat(x,b,i): & \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{N} & \left\lfloor\frac{|x|}{b^i}\right\rfloor\mod b \\ 
\hline \begin{aligned} \text{Number} \\ \text{of Digits}\end{aligned} & nd(x,b): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \lceil\log_b(x+1)\rceil \\
\hline \text{Reverse} & rev(x,b): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \sum_{i=0}^{nd(x,b)-1}dat(x,b,I)\cdot10^{nd(x,b)-i-1} \\ 
\hline \text{Sum Digits} & sd(x,b): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \sum_{i=0}^{nd(x,b)-1}dat(x,b,i)\\ 
\hline \begin{aligned} \text{Look and Say} \\ \text{Counter} \;\;\;\; \end{aligned} & C_\lambda(x,i): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & sd(x\bmod10^i,10) \\
\hline \begin{aligned} \text{Unpadded} \\ \text{Difference} \end{aligned} & \delta(x): & \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \begin{aligned} \sum_{i=0}^{nd(x,10)-2}10^i\cdot \left[ 1-eq(dat(x,10,i), \\ dat(x,10,i+1))\right]  \end{aligned} \\
\hline \begin{aligned} \text{Padded}\;\; \\ \text{Difference} \end{aligned} & \Delta(x): & \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & 10^{nd(x,10)}+10\cdot\delta(x)+1 \\
\hline \begin{aligned} \text{Leftmost}\\ \text{Index} \;\;\; \end{aligned} & il(x,i): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z} & nd(x\bmod10^{i+1},10)-1 \\
\hline\begin{aligned} \text{Rightmost}\\ \text{Index} \;\;\;\; \end{aligned} & ir(x,i): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z} & nd(x,10)-nd\left(rev\left(\left\lfloor\frac{x}{10^{i+1}}\right\rfloor,10\right),10\right) \\
\hline \text{Look and Say} & L(x): & \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \begin{aligned}\sum_{i=0}^{nd(\Delta(x),10)-2}\left[dat(\Delta(x),10,i)\cdot \\ \left(  \left(ir(\Delta(x),i)-i\right)\cdot10^{1+2\cdot C_\lambda(\Delta(x),i)} \\  + dat(x,10,i)\cdot10^{2\cdot C_\lambda(\Delta(x),i)}\right)\right] \end{aligned} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/47jzhkshsm) is a link to desmos, an online calculator, showing the correctness of the function for a few terms. Because of the nature of base $10$, $L(1111111111)=101$ ("ten ones"). Also, due to the limit of computability depth of desmos, large terms are unlikely to work, as desmos rounds intermediate results.

Comment: An algorithm like $L(x_n)=x_{n+1}$ is not considered to be a closed form.  Also, infinite *series* are not considered closed form either.  Anyways, you ought to explicitly say what $L$ is if you have found it.

Comment: I also have a form where $L(i) = x_i$ where $x_i$ is the $i$th term assuming 1 is the first term.

Comment: Let us see it.  But again, infinite series don't count as closed form solutions.  :/  Hope its cool though.

Comment: So, the reason that I have infinite series in the function is that I wanted to write a function that did not depend on the floor/ceil functions. There is an infinite series form of the floor/ceil function. However, allowing the use floor and ceil functions gives a closed form where there are no infinite series. I'm also unsure how to properly "display" it. It's rather large. Would a link to a pdf that contains it be alright?

Comment: I guess yeah.  Put in your question, and if I can format it right, I'll edit it into your question.

Comment: I would recommend against formatting it in the question, since it is sort of large. I'm in the process of writing an explanation and will post that later today or tomorrow. I'm just wondering if anything like this has any use.

Comment: This seems to have the same usefulness as the formulas for the primes (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html): just curiosities.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed.

Comment: Clearly someone found those prime formulas interesting enough to publish, even if they are never the best choice for computation. It's a double strike against a formula if it's inefficient _and_ too complicated to display. You could link to a PDF (maybe in a comment) so we can see how hard it is to format. Note that it is perfectly OK to define a function using other functions that you defined just for that purpose; this is how equation (13) of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html is made more readable than it might have been, using the function $s(j)$ defined in equation (14).

Comment: @DavidK the question has been edited to contain a pdf with all of the definition of $L$ and the other functions it depends on. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-94OKifRzqxWFpYdGpETVdMbXM) is the same link. It is on the second page.

Comment: I think those formulas could be edited directly into the question, though possibly with a short paragraph to introduce each one instead of the tabular format (which I suspect might not fit). An interesting question is what notational alternatives there are for writing the formulas. For example I'd be happy to see $eq(x,y)$ defined using two alternatives on the right of the equation (with a brace and "if" conditions) instead of the sign function.

Comment: I did my best to format it to fit here, and I have to ask if you would like all of your function type stuff to be formatted like I did to the $\operatorname{sgn}$, which normally doesn't display like that.  If someone can make it fit better, please go ahead.  :-)

Comment: @SimpleArt I reduced the font size to make it fit. To me it still seems readable but it might depend.

Comment: @SimpleArt I can't even...

Comment: @SkeletonBow Which part confused you?  :D